# how to solve "TypeError argument of type 'int' is not iterable."

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
for i in range(8):
    ***if by in X[wining[i][0]] and by in X[wining[i][1]] and by in X[wining[i][2]]:***
        checker = 1
        if who == 'P1':
            conter [0] +=1
        elif who == 'P2' :
            conter[1] +=1 
        if vs_player == "boot":
            print "---------YOU WIN!---------"
        elif vs_player =="P2":
            print "---------%s WINER!---------" % who
            print "%s\n\t---------%s---------" % ("""\n %s | %s | %s\n__|___|___\n %s | %s | %s\n__|___|___\n %s | %s | %s """ 
            % (X[0], X[1], X[2], X[3], X[4], X[5], X[6], X[7], X[8]), print_conter)
        del played[:]
        X = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
        break
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: what is `wining`? It looks like it, or either wining[0] is integer. Therefore you can't index it.

Comment: Actually looks like `X` is a list of integers, so `by in X[...]` doesn't make sense.

Comment: wining is an array 2D(wining = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8] , [0, 3, 6],[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8] , [0, 4, 8], [2, 4, 6]]) , and X is list (X = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]), and by is string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try:
    for i in range(8):
        if by in X[wining[i][0]] and by in X[wining[i][1]] and by in X[wining[i][2]]:
            checker = 1
            if who == 'P1':
                conter [0] +=1
            elif who == 'P2' :
                conter[1] +=1 
            if vs_player == "boot":
                print "---------YOU WIN!---------"
            elif vs_player =="P2":
                print "---------%s WINER!---------" % who
                print "%s\n\t---------%s---------" % ("""\n %s | %s | %s\n__|___|___\n %s | %s | %s\n__|___|___\n %s | %s | %s """ 
                % (X[0], X[1], X[2], X[3], X[4], X[5], X[6], X[7], X[8]), print_conter)
            del played[:]
            X = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
            break
excpet:
    typeError
```